# Getting Value of Image Width from JavaScript Image Onload Function

Tags: javascript, onload

I have the following which gets the width of a given image:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image Width</title>
    <script>
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() { 
            alert("Width: " + img.width);
        };
        img.src="http://www.hq.nasa.gov/office/pao/History/alsj/misc/apmisc-60-SAT-1.jpg"

        // Do something with 'img.width' here, outside the image onload event handler.

    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I understand that I need the image to load before getting its width, and how to get its width from *within* the image onload event handler, but I'm having real difficulty accessing its width from *outside* the handler.

Am I just being an idiot and missing something really simple or is it more complex than I think?

Any help would be most appreciated.

Regards, Steve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you face is asynchronous programming. The `onload` function will be called by the engine at a later time, and the program will hold its execution.

There are two options:

1. If you need the value as soon as possible, you'll have to run the code inside `onload`, e.g.:

   ```
   var img = new Image();
   img.onload = function() { 
       alert("Width: " + img.width);
       // Do something with 'img.width' here, outside the image onload event handler.
   };
   img.src="http://www.hq.nasa.gov/office/pao/History/alsj/misc/apmisc-60-SAT-1.jpg"
   ```
2. If the code that will access `img.width` will happen later, e.g. after user clicks something, you can store the value and use it elsewhere:

   ```
   var width;

   var img = new Image();
   img.onload = function() { 
       width = img.width;
   };
   img.src="http://www.hq.nasa.gov/office/pao/History/alsj/misc/apmisc-60-SAT-1.jpg"

   function anotherFunction() {
       alert(width);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you @Lukasz. I guess I'll need to introduce some arbitrary delay before calling `anotherFunction()` to (hopefully) ensure the onload handler's finished, but I may well go with your first suggestion and run the code inside the handler as it seems less error prone. Thanks.

Comment: Absolutely, that's the way to go: call `anotherFunction()` (or any code depending on the width) from within `onload`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but if you want to access the image's width then I suggest you read some more about asynchronous code.

What the `img.onload = function() {}` code does is to **schedule** the function to be called after the image has been loaded.
However the code that follows it is just being executed immediately (*synchronously*) after the scheduling takes place, which most surely will precede the image's being loaded.

Hence, you need to delay its execution until the image is loaded, which is exactly what `img.onload` is meant for.